# How can I attach files in articles?

Tags: hyperref, color, attachfile

I'm having issues attaching files in an article. It returns 2 errors: one related with `color` and the other with `hyperref`:

1. ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package `color`.
2. ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package `hyperref`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[unicode]{attachfile}


\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=false, % true means bookmarks in 
                                     % left window are numbered                         
            bookmarksopen=false,     % true means only level 1
                                     % are displayed.
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=rojo_javi,
            urlcolor=azul_alberto]{hyperref} 

\definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0} % less intense green
\definecolor{webblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}  % less intense blue
\definecolor{webred}{rgb}{0.5, 0, 0}   % less intense red
\definecolor{dblackcolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{dbluecolor}{rgb}{.01,.02,0.7}
\definecolor{dredcolor}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\definecolor{dgraycolor}{rgb}{0.30,0.3,0.30}
\definecolor{azul_alberto}{rgb}{.01,.02,0.9}
\definecolor{rojo_javi}{rgb}{0.5, 0, 0}


\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\attachfile[icon=PushPin]{files/z_LM7805_datasheet.pdf}

\end{document}
```

What can I do??

Answer (score 2):

Load [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and change the setting using `\hypersetup`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile2}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{azul_alberto}{rgb}{.01,.02,0.9}
\definecolor{rojo_javi}{rgb}{0.5, 0, 0}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  bookmarksnumbered=false, % true means bookmarks in
                           % left window are numbered
  bookmarksopen=false,     % true means only level 1
                           % are displayed.
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=rojo_javi,
  urlcolor = azul_alberto
}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\attachfile[icon=PushPin]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Also, use [`attachfile2`](//ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2).

Comment: Is this essentially saying, the answer is the following: ... use `attachfile2` version and define the colors before they are set in hyperref?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer: Roughly, but you can define the colours afterwards. It's just unconventional to use something before it's defined.